# Some times barcode is not loading, with IDAutomationHC39M style

Tags: barcode

While showing barcode using IDAutomationHC39M font, some times not loading the barcode instead showing number with asterisk. would be great any material on IDAutomationHC39M.

below is the code to generate barcode.

```
<td style="font-family: IDAutomationHC39M; font-size:12px;">*${dynaming_number}*</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble in the past using inline styles. Have you tried creating CSS and a custom class?

Then again, it might just be the font-family you are using, try to load the font with the fontlibrary.org link, and then use "IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode" instead of "IDAutomationHC39M".

```js
var buttonGen = document.getElementById("btnGen");
buttonGen.onclick = function () {
  var x = document.getElementById("textIn").value;
  var fs;

  // Change the font-size style to match the drop down
  fs = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[document.getElementById("selList").selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("test").style.fontSize = fs  + 'px';
  
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =
    '*' + // Start Code B
    x + // The originally typed string
    '*'; // Stop Code
}
```

```css
td, th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px;
}
.ss {
  font-family: "IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode";
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/idautomationhc39m-code-39-barcode" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
  &nbsp;Font Size:&nbsp;
  <select id="selList">
    <option value="24" selected>24px</option>
    <option value="30">30px</option>
    <option value="36">36px</option>
    <option value="42">42px</option>
    <option value="48">48px</option>
    <option value="54">54px</option>
    <option value="60">60px</option>
    <option value="66">66px</option>
    <option value="72">72px</option>
    <option value="78">78px</option>
    <option value="84">84px</option>
    <option value="90">90px</option>
    <option value="96">96px</option>
  </select>&nbsp;

  <input type="text" id="textIn"></input>
  <input type="button" id="btnGen" value="Generate Code 39" tabindex=4/>
  <div id="check"></div><br /><span id="test" class="ss">*Making the Web Beautiful*</span><br />
  <p>This is a demonstration of use of the Free ID Automation 39 Font.</p>
</body>
```